How can I scan QR code from an image on web
I have a flutter project and I want to also deploy it on the web, but for the QR code section, I want to upload an image and scan the QR code from the image on the web platform. Because I think it is more practical for web usage. I can upload the image, there is no problem with that, but I cannot scan the qr code from the uploaded image. I cannot find so many resources about that.
I currently use the mobile scanner package for QR code reading, and I saw it has a function to read from images. Still, as indicated in the documentation, it only works on Android and iOS platforms. How can I achieve, what I want for the web platform?

You can use this package flutter_web_qrcode_scanner in order to use qr scanning in web
